# Binary (image) data clipboard in macOS

Tags: macos, clipboard

When I copy things to the clipboard, I can dump them into my console window or redirect to a file using:

`pbpaste > out.txt`

But if I right click an image and copy it in a browser, then attempt:

`pbpaste > out.jpg`

Nothing is outputted.

Where does macOS store the image data in the clipboard? Is there some way to access it from the commandline, similarly to pbpaste?

Comment: i would also like to see this implemented. @Jamie Wong - do you use quicksilver? (qsapp.com) they have a neat plugin for screen capture actions. it can capture a region and then send it to a file of your choosing, and then you can "act" on it.

Comment: Used to - switched to http://www.alfredapp.com/. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: I tried Alfred but QS is just so much more powerful and extensible. do you know QS has a new version released last month? U should check it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In response to a question from [Jeff](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11100/whats-the-quickest-way-to-get-a-graphic-on-the-clipboard-saved-to-disk?newsletter=1&nlcode=13163%7cb8f3) a [utility](http://github.com/jcsalterego/pngpaste) was written to let you paste graphics to a PNG.

Comment: So awesome, thanks for posting this! I wish there was a general purpose tool that I could use for JPGs/GIFs as well, but this'll do nicely in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

`man pbpaste` says that it only looks for plain text, rich text, or encapsulated postscript.  I don't know any command that handles more general pasteboard data, but it probably wouldn't be hard to write one.

Comment: Any idea where is the data stored? Is it shoved directly into memory, into some standard temporary file?

Comment: I don't know where the data is stored, but why do you care?  You can access it with APIs (Carbon or Cocoa).

Comment: I care because it's extremely convenient to be able to use pbcopy and pbpaste from the command line. It allows me to avoid going through finder just to copy the contents of a file in my current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for how to store arbitrary binary data in the clipboard, it seems this may not be practical. In part, I believe because there's only a [handful of types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard/pasteboardtype) the pasteboard accepts. None of which are suitable for arbitrary unformatted data.

You can seemingly lie to the pasteboard and place arbitrary data into one of the non-string types like, [PDF pasteboardType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard/pasteboardtype/1529966-pdf) and later read the same data back from the clipboard.

Using the Python [pasteboard](https://github.com/tobywf/pasteboard) package, (a small Objective-C program with Python bindings) this can be demonstrated:

```py
import secrets
data = secrets.token_bytes(100) # generate random bytes
import pasteboard
pb = pasteboatd.Pasteboard()
# set the data to the pasteboard
pb.set_contents(data, pasteboard.PDF)
# get the contents back, same as before
pb.get_contents(pasteboard.PDF) == data # True
```